# docker file with two images

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create an image Docker for einstore Apps and for that I need images with docker and with the command make déjà installé to run this cmd `"make install-db"`
for that I create this docker file

```
FROM einstore/einstore-base:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN make install-db
```

the problem is that in this image "einstore-base" we have to make cmd but I don't have docker
when I try to replace this image with docker latest I can found docker but I can't do something with make cmd
so I want an image with these two cmd or I want a method where I can mixte 2 images if there are any options like that and thank you

Comment: here is no real way of "mixing" two docker images as a docker image is basically a virtual machine. I'm not really sure what you try to achieve and which is you base Docker image, but you can install programs such as "make" or other things. I guess you can install a docker image within another but i don't really see the point.

the make command needs a makefile to run commands, so maybe you are lacking the makefile ?

Comment: i want to debloy einstore in rancher with helm chart To be able to do that I have to put it in a image docker, And I need inside it Docker cmd and Make cmd i aleardy have makefile butI need the original image that is basically a virtual machine will consider to have Docker and make cmd i try to do FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from your host to your current working directory
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install make
#RUN apt install docker.io
RUN sudo apt install docker.io
RUN make install-db
but i still cant install docker inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look a [Docker's multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). I have used this before to build an Angular app using the `npm` image and then create a server image using the `nginx` image, if I remember correctly.

These images in particular won't help you, but you could first use `einstore/einstore-base:latest` to `RUN` the `make` command. In the same `Dockerfile` you can then use the `docker:latest` image you mentioned to use the `docker` command.

This only works if the two commands do not depend on each other. If they do you'll be better off with choosing one of the two images and then manually install the libraries necessary for running the missing command. If that suits you, you can also create a new image from that and cut out the repetitive process of downloading and installing those libraries.